# tslint doesn't work in the latest Angular version

Tags: angular, eslint, tslint

I'm using **Angular 10** (latest version) and **tslint 6.1.0**.
I added the following rule inside rules object in **tslint.json** file:

```
"no-any": [true, { "ignore-rest-args": true }]
```

And I added the following code to app.component.ts file:

```
constructor() {
    this.sayHey("Hey")
}

sayHey(message: any): any {
    console.log(message);
}
```

As you can see I'm using `any` everywhere but there's no error shown in my vs-code.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by installing the following extention:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin